# How do I get return self.func(*args) to work in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have just started my first Python project (sorry if this is a dumb question I am just starting out) and am using the Tkinter interface. I seem to keep on receiving this prompt:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Apps\Python\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in ****call****
> return self.func(*args)
> File "c:/Users/noahc/Documents/Programming/AppLauncher/AppLauncher.py", line 62, in 
> resetList = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=lambda:[removeSave(),resetList()])
> TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

I have provided the code below:

```
#########################
# CREATED BY NOZZYPOZZY #
#########################
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("App Launcher")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/noahc/Documents/Programming/AppLauncher/icon.ico')
root.resizable(0,0)

apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt','r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = tempApps
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]


def addApp():

    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File", filetypes=(("Executables","*.exe"), ("All Files", "*.*")))\

    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
        label.pack()

def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)

def resetList():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

def removeSave():
    os.remove('save.txt')



canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="gray")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=addApp)
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=runApps)
runApps.pack()

resetList = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=lambda:[removeSave(),resetList()])
resetList.pack()




for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()


with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
        f.write(app + ',')
```

Comment: The code shown in your exception traceback doesn't match the code you provided. The `return self.func(*args)` in your exception message isn't from your code; it's from Tkinter's internal implementation. So obviously it's not a matter of how to make that work, because it isn't your code. At any rate, the source of the error is as explained - you're trying to use `resetList` to name two different things. The overall lesson here is that you need to *pay more attention* to what you are reading and writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean that after you hit reset, then "Open File" and it populates your list with the previous entries? When you execute `resetList`, you just remove the items from the display, but keep your `apps` list populated, so when you call `addApp`, this list is loaded and displayed again with the new element at the end. You could fix that by calling `apps.clear()` in your `resetList` function, which will delete all entries in `apps`. – answer by @Talon

Answer (score 3):

Your function `resetList` shares a name with your Button variable. Instead of your function, it tries to call itself.

On this line:

```
resetList = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=lambda:[removeSave(),resetList()])
```

You're using the lambda function to execute the function `removeSave` and `resetList`. The problem is that the variable you're assigning this button too is also called `resetList`. We can check that when we replace the function call and instead print out what `resetList` is:

```
resetList = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=lambda:[removeSave(),print(repr(resetList))])
```

Upon execution this will give us 
`<tkinter.Button object .!button3>`
You called your function `resetList`, but overwrote that with the button that is also called `resetList`, so instead of executing the function with `resetList()`, your program tries to execute the button. You can fix that for example by renaming your Button variable, e.g.:

```
reset_list_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=lambda:[removeSave(),resetList()])
reset_list_button.pack()
```

Comment: What do you mean? There are 2 functions that I've got going through the command of the reset button

Comment: thanks so much @talon it worked. Just wondering do u know how to keep the text deleted?

Comment: I suppose you mean that after you hit reset, then "Open File" and it populates your list with the previous entries? When you execute `resetList`, you just remove the items from the display, but keep your `apps` list populated, so when you call `addApp`, this list is loaded and displayed again with the new element at the end. You could fix that by calling `apps.clear()` in your `resetList` function, which will delete all entries in `apps`.